# Replacing width values in PHP (With Conditions)

Tags: replace, width, preg-replace

I know there has been questions on replacing width values with PHP before and that's not really where my issue lays.

```
$contentWidth = 'width="600"';

$screenContent = get_the_content();
$screenContent = preg_replace("/width=\"(.*?)\"/is", $contentWidth, $screenContent);
echo $screenContent;
```

That's what I have so far and it's working fine. But I want to add a condition to only make the change when the width is over 600; just to ensure that I don't distort image quality.

Is there any way to assign the width to a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to grab the portion of $screenContent that interests you:

```
$screenContent = get_the_content();
if(preg_match("/width=\"(.*?)\"/is", $contentWidth, $match)) {
    // width is stored in $match[1] (the matching portion is in $match[0])
    if(is_numeric($match[1]) && $match[1] > 600)
        $screenContent = preg_replace("/width=\"(.*?)\"/is", $contentWidth, $screenContent);
}

echo $screenContent;
```

Make sure to check for a valid width (is_numeric above) since your greedy matcher (.*?) allows characters AND numbers.

Comment: That's brilliant, I was thinking it would be something like that.

Is there any way I can replace .*? to only get the number values so even if it's width="600px" for example, it will only grab and replace the 600 bit?

Comment: Sure, something like /width=\"?([0-9]+)[^\"\w>]*\"?/is (haven't tested it)

Comment: Okay an issue with the code you gave me. It only replaces the first match. 

`$contentWidth = 'width="600"';

$screenContent = get_the_content();
      if(preg_match("/width=\"(.*?)\"/is", $screenContent, $match))
{
 for($i=1; $i<=count($match); $i++)
 {
  if(is_numeric($match[$i]) && $match[$i] > 600)
  {
      $screenContent .= preg_replace("/width=\"(.*?)\"/is", $contentWidth, $match[$i]);
  }
 }
}
echo $screenContent;`

That's what I have so far but I'm sure you can see the flaw. Is there any way I can preg_replace certain matches within a variable?

Comment: If you want to change multiple instances of the match individually, you'll have to do some form of str_replace or strpos checking against the items in the match array.